# Python 3 using concurrent futures ProcessPool in Daemon context

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures, python-daemon

I am trying to use the concurrent.futures ProcessPool executor withon the python Daemon() context (ThreadPool is working) and every submitted task is getting stuck in state running.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import daemon
import sys

class Daemon():

    def __init__(self):

        print("init")

        self.context = daemon.DaemonContext(
                stdout = sys.stdout
                )

        with self.context:

            self.__run()

    def task(self, n):

        start = time.time()
        time.sleep(n)
        duration = time.time() - start

        return n, duration


    def __run(self):

        try:

            #e = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3)
            e = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(3)
            fut = e.submit(self.task, 2)

            while not fut.done():

                print(fut)
                time.sleep(0.5)

            res = fut.result()
            print(res)

            e.shutdown(wait=True)

        except Exception as e:

            print(e)

        finally:

            print("stopped")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Daemon()
```

Outputs:

```
# venv/bin/python conc.py
init
<Future at 0x7f85195c8588 state=running>
<Future at 0x7f85195c8588 state=running>
<Future at 0x7f85195c8588 state=running>
[...]
```

when ThreadPoolExecutor is correctly stopping after 2 seconds:

```
<Future at 0x7f38fd450668 state=running>
<Future at 0x7f38fd450668 state=running>
(30, 2.002039670944214)
stopping
```

Since the concurrent code is running without the daemon, I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

I am using python 3.5.3 and python-daemon 2.1.2

Comment: Discard the '30' in the output. Copy & paste mistake (has to be '2')